# Using find with variable inside regex

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use find in order to get a targeted file for my sh script

```
PREVIOUS_FILE="FX00.txt"

var=$(find /usr1/fida -regextype posix-extended  -regex  "$PREVIOUS_FILE\.(ok|false)")
```

When execution ends var is empty.

I want to find

```
FX00.txt.ok
```

If I execute it in normal shell it works.Any suggestions?

Best regards!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `find` for this rather than just using functionality built in to bash, like `globstar` and `extglob`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `find`'s manual:

> -regex *pattern*
>
> > File name matches regular expression *pattern*.  **This is a match on the whole path, not a search.**  For example, to match a file named `./fubar3`, you can use the regular expression `.*bar.`  or  `.*b.*3`,  but not `f.*r3`.